# Feasibility of Kubernetes helm deploying using Helm client from Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to implement the Kubernetes service deployment using Kubernetes helm chart. Actually I am using Jenkins pipeline job for deployment. And Jenkins is installed out side of Kubernetes cluster. So If I am using Helm in the machine where Jenkins is installed , then can I use Helm deployment command inside on Jenkins pipeline job?

If I am calling "helm install" command inside one Jenkins pipeline job ? Does it deploy into remote Kubernetes cluster? Because I am installing Jenkins out side of Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I am calling "helm install" command inside one jenkins pipeline job
>   ? Does it deploy into remote kubernetes cluster?

Yes. You need a `~/.kube/config` file, network access to the k8s API, `kubectl` and `helm` to make it work.

Here's a good read explaining helm https://next.nutanix.com/kubernetes-containers-30/tillerless-helm-on-nutanix-karbon-31334

Comment: How I need to get /.kube/config and kubectl in this machine where I am trying to install helm ? Because this machine is not in kubernetes cluster. If I am installing helm , should available here? .

Comment: `~/.kube/config` depends of how you installed k8s: kops - https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_export_kubecfg.md , eks - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html . Everything else - get from package manager

Comment: They are not available on machines within k8s cluster either.